# Textbook/lecture notes on the quantum aspects of Black holes

Tags: black-holes

Please suggest beginner-level textbooks or lecture notes on the quantum aspects of black holes. I mean Hawking radiation, Blackhole evaporation, entanglement, etc without knowing string theory. I am not familiar with string theory at all at a technical level. I want to learn things leisurely in baby steps.

Comment: Would you be more precise? By "quantum aspects of black holes", you mean semi-classical ones? string theoretical means of computing the black hole entropy? what aspects of black holes you're exactly interested in?

Comment: I mean Hawking radiation, Blackhole evaporation, entanglement etc. I am not familiar with string theory at all at a technical level.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your answer providing details on what exactly you want to know to help others to give good and concrete recommendations. The paper [Jerusalem Lectures on Black Holes and Quantum Information](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1231) is an excellent, modern and pedagogical introductory resource.

Comment: Try Hartman's lecture notes. It assumes some background in GR, QM and QFT though.

Comment: @thunderbolt thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mithusengupta, you have asked a good question as there are a lot great books out there, about the topic. But I would recommend ICTS lectures of Gautum Mandal about Hawking radiation, but even learning from lectures, you should have a prior knowledge of Black holes, for that you should read Chandrasekhar book THE MATHEMATICAL THEORY OF BLACK HOLES. For books, originally, I recommend the book, QUANTUM ASPECTS OF BLACK HOLES of the Springer series of Fundamental theories of Physics. It covers the topics you need. Hope it helps...